# Compare 2 different size dataframes in Python (df1 and df2) and ouput everything from df2 not in df1 and put into df3

Tags: python, pandas

df1 contains a static list of names that will not change, while df2 contains names that are constantly changing. I am attempting to compare df2 against df1 and output any names from df2 not contained in df1.

Trying:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Sally', 'Bill']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Sue', 'Bob', 'Steve', 'Jenna']})

df3 = ~pd.DataFrame(df1['Name'].isin(df2['Name']))
print('Names not found in df1:', df3)
```

Wanted Output:

Names not found in df1:
Sue
Bob
Steve
Jenna

Answer (score 1):

`difference_df = df1.compare(df2)` should do the trick?

Comment: I've tried this and got the following error: "Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame object"
I believe this error is because the dataframes are 2 different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the difference in sets between df2 and df1

```
set(df2['Name']) - set(df1['Name'])
```

Output:
`{'Bob', 'Jenna', 'Steve', 'Sue'}`